# zenburn visual studio theme for c++

Tags: c++, color-scheme

Seems all the zenburn VS themes are for c# or other .net languages, is there any zenburn theme available for c++?

Comment: For Visual Studio? They're the same themes as C#...

Comment: ya. What I want is a specially modified edition which handles c++ keywords/grammar well.